# Count data in array where date is the same and build chart bar morrisjs

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
array (    [0] => 2014-06-01 12:45:02
    [1] => 2014-06-01 12:45:03
    [2] => 2014-06-01 12:48:52
    [3] => 2014-06-01 12:50:31
    [4] => 2014-06-01 13:18:49
    [10] => 2014-06-01 13:33:16
    [11] => 2014-06-01 14:20:48
    [12] => 2014-06-01 14:24:44
    [13] => 2014-06-01 15:28:16
    [14] => 2014-06-02 10:50:56
    [15] => 2014-06-02 10:51:07
    [16] => 2014-06-02 18:16:13
    [17] => 2014-06-03 11:20:20
    [18] => 2014-06-03 11:58:46
    [19] => 2014-06-03 11:59:03
    [20] => 2014-06-03 12:00:51
    [21] => 2014-06-03 12:01:21
    [22] => 2014-06-04 19:03:17
    [23] => 2014-06-04 19:06:03
    [24] => 2014-06-04 19:12:03
    [25] => 2014-06-04 21:18:03
)
```

etc... about 30 records, the idea is to get how many "dates" are "the same" 2014-06-01, 2014-06-02, 2014-06-03... etc... so that can get a final result as:
From date 2014-06-01 you logged (9) times
From date 2014-06-02 you logged (3) times
... etc
and with that information I can build a morrisjs chart bar, but I have no idea how to count the dates... now this data I can latter compare with the "last" month or year... but like I said, I have no idea how to count the records because when I use array_count_values it also check for the time and I don't need the time just the date, and the result is not correct, since it count all of the records not the "group" records from same date..

Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$data = array (    '0' => '2014-06-01 12:45:02',
    '1' => '2014-06-01 12:45:03',
    '2' => '2014-06-01 12:48:52',
    '3' => '2014-06-01 12:50:31',
    '4' => '2014-06-01 13:18:49',
    '10' => '2014-06-01 13:33:16',
    '11' => '2014-06-01 14:20:48',
    '12' => '2014-06-01 14:24:44',
    '13' => '2014-06-01 15:28:16',
    '14' => '2014-06-02 10:50:56',
    '15' => '2014-06-02 10:51:07',
    '16' => '2014-06-02 18:16:13',
    '17' => '2014-06-03 11:20:20',
    '18' => '2014-06-03 11:58:46',
    '19' => '2014-06-03 11:59:03',
    '20' => '2014-06-03 12:00:51',
    '21' => '2014-06-03 12:01:21',
    '22' => '2014-06-04 19:03:17',
    '23' => '2014-06-04 19:06:03',
    '24' => '2014-06-04 19:12:03',
    '25' => '2014-06-04 21:18:03',
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $array= explode(" ",$data[$key]);
   $array_result[] = $array[0];
}
$vals = array_count_values($array_result);

print_r($vals);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [2014-06-01] => 9
    [2014-06-02] => 3
    [2014-06-03] => 5
    [2014-06-04] => 4
)
```

Comment: explode, reassign, count. i like it. and without unnecessary function calls to strtotime() or date().

Comment: Haha I sense sarcasm @Jens-AndréKoch

Comment: i mean it! why should someone waste exec time on date() or strtotime(), when one can simply split the string. a little optimization would be to switch from explode() to substr(), catching only the first 10 chars. ,)

Comment: Well everyone has it own way to do things i guess!

Comment: Well this just give me some room for more information since the whole array is a multidimensional array... the use of strtotime() or date() is unnecessary... the simple the better...

Comment: Some comments with good arguments and the deal is settled ;) Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25047285/1163786

Answer (score 2):

`array_count_values()` will return an array with the dates as keys and the number of times they appear in the array as values.  But first, build an array of just the dates without time:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
}
$counts = array_count_values($dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the times from the dates using [**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then use [**array_count_values()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the date occurrences.

```
$new_array = 
    array_map(function($x){return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($x));}, $array);

$date_count = array_count_values($new_array);
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/qva50)

Answer (score 1):

Based on user3350731 solution, but with substr() instead of explode().

```
<?php

$data = array (
    '0' => '2014-06-01 12:45:02',
    '1' => '2014-06-01 12:45:03',
    '2' => '2014-06-01 12:48:52',
    '3' => '2014-06-01 12:50:31',
    '4' => '2014-06-01 13:18:49',
    '10' => '2014-06-01 13:33:16',
    '11' => '2014-06-01 14:20:48',
    '12' => '2014-06-01 14:24:44',
    '13' => '2014-06-01 15:28:16',
    '14' => '2014-06-02 10:50:56',
    '15' => '2014-06-02 10:51:07',
    '16' => '2014-06-02 18:16:13',
    '17' => '2014-06-03 11:20:20',
    '18' => '2014-06-03 11:58:46',
    '19' => '2014-06-03 11:59:03',
    '20' => '2014-06-03 12:00:51',
    '21' => '2014-06-03 12:01:21',
    '22' => '2014-06-04 19:03:17',
    '23' => '2014-06-04 19:06:03',
    '24' => '2014-06-04 19:12:03',
    '25' => '2014-06-04 21:18:03',
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $array_result[] = substr($value, 0, 10);
}

$vals = array_count_values($array_result);

print_r($vals);
```

Note: no calls to strtotime(), date() or array_map().

Answer (score 0):

Make another variable that holds your dates and a counter. Go over your dates in your initial array and add 1 to the counter in the other array.

Example:

```
$dateCounters = array();
foreach($initialArray as $date){
    $niceDate = date('Y-m-d', $date);
    if(in_array($dateCounters, $niceDate){
        $dateCounters[$niceDate] += 1;
    } else {
        $dateCounters[$niceDate] = 1;
    }
}
```