# Sum values in array and simplify key names

Tags: php, arrays

This is almost similar to my other question which is related to the same project I'm working on.. [Link to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046786/count-data-in-array-where-date-is-the-same-and-build-chart-bar-morrisjs)
but in this case the array is different as follow:

```
Array
(
    [2014-08-01 11:27:03] => 2
    [2014-08-01 11:52:57] => 2
    [2014-08-01 11:54:49] => 2
    [2014-08-02 11:59:54] => 4
    [2014-08-02 12:02:41] => 2
    [2014-08-05 12:09:38] => 4
    [2014-08-07 12:23:12] => 3
    [2014-08-07 12:25:18] => 3
// and so on...
)
```

That is my output array and in order to get that array I had to do some miracles... anyway, so based on that array I have to sum the value for each key date and build an array something like this...

```
Array
(
    [2014-08-01] => 6
    [2014-08-02] => 6
    [2014-08-05] => 4
    [2014-08-07] => 6
// and so on...
)
```

That last array will be use to build graphs with morrisonJS, what I have is this:

```
$res_meno = array();
foreach ($sunArr as $keys => $values) {
    $arrays= explode(" ",$sumArr[$keys]);
    $res_meno[] = $arrays[0];
}
$vals_char2 = array_count_values($res_meno);
```

That is my attempt to build my last array but is not working...
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: morrisonJS? maybe `morrisJS`

Comment: yes, that is what I mean... morrisJS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this PHP Code You Can test [here](https://eval.in/177265)**

```
    $sunArr = Array
    (
        '2014-08-01 11:27:03' => 2,
        '2014-08-01 11:52:57' => 2,
        '2014-08-01 11:54:49' => 2,
        '2014-08-02 11:59:54' => 4,
        '2014-08-02 12:02:41' => 2,
        '2014-08-05 12:09:3' => 4,
        '2014-08-07 12:23:12' => 3,
        '2014-08-07 12:25:18' => 3

    );

    $key = 0;
    $res_meno = array();
    foreach ($sunArr as $keys => $values)
    {
        $ar= explode(" ", $keys);

        if( $key == $ar[0] )
        {       
            $res_meno[$key] = $sunArr[$keys] + $res_meno[$key];
        }
        else
        {
            $key = $ar[0];
            $res_meno[$key] = $values;      
        }  
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res_meno);
    die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
 "2014-08-01 11:27:03" => 2,
 "2014-08-01 11:52:57" => 2,
 "2014-08-01 11:54:49" => 2,
 "2014-08-02 11:59:54" => 4,
 "2014-08-02 12:02:41" => 2,
 "2014-08-05 12:09:38" => 4,
 "2014-08-07 12:23:12" => 3,
 "2014-08-07 12:25:18" => 3
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
   $date = reset(explode(" ", $k));
   if(isset($new_array[$date])){
      $new_array[$date] += $v;
   }
   else{
     $new_array[$date] = $v;
   }
}
print_r($new_array);

?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/177263)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sunArr = array
(
    "2014-08-01 11:27:03" => 2,
    "2014-08-01 11:52:57" => 2,
    "2014-08-01 11:54:49" => 2,
    "2014-08-02 11:59:54" => 4,
    "2014-08-02 12:02:41" => 2,
    "2014-08-05 12:09:38" => 4,
    "2014-08-07 12:23:12" => 3,
    "2014-08-07 12:25:18" => 3,
);

  $res_meno = array();

    foreach ($sunArr as $keys => $values) {

        $arrays= explode(" ",$keys);

        if(isset($res_meno[$arrays[0]]))
        {
           $res_meno[$arrays[0]] = $res_meno[$arrays[0]] + $values;
        }
        else
        {
           $res_meno[$arrays[0]] = $values;
        }
    }

    print_r($res_meno);
    exit;
```

Try this, i think it might fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Where does the first array come from? If it's from a SQL database, it's better to create a query that returns the aggregated array.

Otherwise no need to use array_key_values for that:

```
$res_meno = array();
foreach ($sumArr as $keys => $values) {
    $key = substr($keys, 0, 10);
    $res_meno[$key] = (empty($res_meno[$key]) ? 0 : $res_meno[$key]) + $values;
}
```

Comment: Yes and no, the first array is from a SQL(yes) but the column that holds the information is not a simple string, is a json with a multidimensional array which has deep 4 groups and the "Date Time" is a single column... so, I have to count the whatever is inside group 4 from the json and then associated it with the column date-time...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses a callback. **Not to use loops is often better!**

```
$sunArr = array(
    '2014-08-01 11:27:03' => 3,
    '2014-08-01 11:27:05' => 5,
    '2013-09-01 11:01:05' => 1
);

$res = array();
function map($item, $key, &$result)
{
    $result[current(explode(" ", $key))] += $item;
}

array_walk($sunArr, "map", &$res);
var_dump($res);
```

You can test it [here on codepad](http://codepad.org/FumPvjvO).